# Taking mean of only specific values from each row in a DataFrame while grouping rows with the same index name and ignoring Nan?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

If I have a DataFrame where I want to group rows with the same index name, say:

```
  a   b   c
c 2   1   -
c nan 2   -
d 4   3   -
e 5   4   -
d 6   5   -
```

I want to merge rows with the same column name, while taking the average of their values in column a and b. So that df would turn into:

```
  a  b 
c 2  1.5 
d 5  4
e 5  4
```

If I do:

```
averaging = df.groupby(["Index"])[['a', 'b']].mean()
```

("Index" is the name set for the rows)

That works, except it doesn't ignore nan. So instead of my desired dataframe, I get:

```
  a   b
c nan 1.5
d 5   4
e 5   4
```

Comment: remove nan first?

Comment: What would be the method for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can using `mean` with `level=0`

```
pd.to_numeric(df.a,errors='coerce').mean(level=0)
Out[438]: 
c    2.0
d    5.0
e    5.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Also nan is not NaN , using `replace`

```
df=df.replace('nan',np.nan)
```

Comment: What if I want to include multiple columns, so take the average from column b as well?

Comment: @user10366926 `df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').mean(level=0)`

Comment: But what if there's another column c, which I don't want the average of? So the columns are a, b, and c, I want the averages from columns a and b

Comment: @user10366926 `df[['a','b']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').mean(level=0)`